# System.Timers.Timer thread is not exiting, stopping Console App to finish

Tags: c#

I have a very simple Console application which fires Timer.Elapsed after every 2 seconds. Console application exit, but I am still seeing my Console.exe in Task Explorer with fixed Memory, Fixed Threads and 0 CPU usage. Here is my simple Console app,

```
    private static bool _allWorkFinsihed;
    private static Timer _timer;
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();
    private static void Main()
    {
        SetTimer();
        while (true)
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                if (_allWorkFinsihed)
                {
                    _timer.Enabled = false;
                    _timer.Dispose();
                    break;
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    private static void SetTimer()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(2000.0);
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                DoBackgroundStuff();
            }
        };
        lock (Lock)
        {
            _timer.Enabled = true;    
        }
    }

    private static void DoBackgroundStuff()
    {
        if (_allWorkFinsihed || !_timer.Enabled)
        {
            return;
        }
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        // Do my Background stuff
        if (condition)
        {
            _allWorkFinsihed = true;
        }
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I found that it is working the Console.vshost.exe confused me.

Comment: Do you ever see `DoBackgroundStuff` getting called in the debugger?

Comment: Yes. During Debugging I found that everythings is running. But I don't know what is stopping my process to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer you initialize somehow keeps your program alive.
For this you need to dispose it.

For example:

```
using (var t = SetTimer()) 
{
   while (true)
   {
      lock (Lock)
      {
         if (_allWorkFinsihed)
         {
            t.Enabled = false;
            t.Dispose();
            break;
         }
      }
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
   }

   t.Enabled = false; 
}
```

Note that `SetTimer`, in this case, returns newly constructed `Timer` object.

**EDIT**

```
private static Timer SetTimer()
{
    _timer = new Timer(2000.0);
    _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            DoBackgroundStuff();
        }
    };
    lock (Lock)
    {
        _timer.Enabled = true;    
    }

    return _timer;
 }
```

Comment: But I need to use _timer in my DoBackgroundStuff where I need to enable and disable _timer.

Comment: @user960567: you can. I changed the name of variable to meet your naming .

Comment: Where should I declare `Timer _timer;` inside the method?

Comment: I think ConsoleApp.vshost.exe confused me